# Why does my FactoryBot definition not see my lambda definition (Ruby,Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am attempting to define a lambda in a FactoryBot like so...

```
    contact_methods = %w[Phone Email Snail\ Mail Carrier\ Pigeon]

    factory :my_object do
        transient do
          remove_used_value = -> (x,y) { x.reject { |a| a == y }.sample }
        end
        first_contact_option { contact_methods.sample }
        second_contact_option { remove_used_value.call(contact_methods,first_contact_option) }
    end
```

However, when I run `FactoryBot.create(:my_object)` I get the error `undefined method remove_used_value for #<FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner:0x00007fb2ac238960>`

I define this as a lambda because there are several other fields that need this same functionality in the Bot. The strange thing is that this was working just fine yesterday, except the logic in the lambda wasn't returning the expected result. After reworking the logic and testing the lambda in the CLI I figured out logic that works, but all of the sudden it's not recognizing the lambda is there.

Is there something wrong with my definition? Also, is there a more preferred way of doing something like this either way?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably replacing this assignment

```
remove_used_value = -> (x,y) { x.reject { |a| a == y }.sample }
```

with the proper dynamic attribute defined via a block

```
remove_used_value { -> (x,y) { x.reject { |a| a == y }.sample } }
```

will fix the issue.

(To be honest, I would avoid such kind of randomization of the object properties that I don't control in full - this often leads to either flaky specs that fail all of a sudden or, even worse, subtle bugs in the app logic that were not caught by the specs; but I understand that it might be a good solution for the particular use case)